# passing class for method parameter angular

Tags: angular, typescript

@Edit

i have a table of user can insert a new data or update a item of table, in all cases he create or update in one componente, because are only in max 3 inputs,
but he can create or edit a lot of things, how section, marca, and etc.
when he acess a item a pass with query parameter what he want create or edit. if is secao or marca for example. and actualy i'm using swicth case for se wath data he want create or edit:

```
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe( params =>{
       this.id = params['id'];
       this.nome = params['nome'];
       this.descricao = params['descricao'];
       this.podeFracionar = params['podeFracionar'];
       this.entidade = params['entidade'];

       if(this.id !== undefined) this.atualizar = true;
      });
```

> 

```
switch(this.entidade){
     case 'secao':
          if(this.atualizar){
            this.secaoService.update(this.id, this.entidadesForm.value).subscribe(secao => {
              this.location.back()
            },
          erro => console.log(erro))
          }else{
            this.secaoService.save(this.entidadesForm.value).subscribe(secao=>{
              this.location.back()
             },
           erro =>{
             console.log(erro)
           })
          }
          break;

          case 'marca':
          if(this.atualizar){
            this.marcaService.update(this.id, this.entidadesForm.value).subscribe(secao => {
              this.location.back()
            },
          erro => console.log(erro))
          }else{
            this.marcaService.save(this.entidadesForm.value).subscribe(secao=>{
              this.location.back()
             },
           erro =>{
             console.log(erro)
           })
          }
          break;
```

}

in all cases i call a service for save or update.
I can create a service for each case and pass class how parameter in method for call the respective class, or has other form to optimize it?

@Edit thank you for response my question. Now i want know how i can remove this switch case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that its better if you factorize you `service` class instead to have two services just create one  with the method `update(..., ... , type)` and `save(..., type)` you will have an smaller `switch` event you can create another function like this:

```
      case 'secao':
      callRepository('secao')
      break;

      case 'marca':
      callRepository('marca') 
      break;

    callRepository(type){
          if(this.atualizar){
            this.customService.update(this.id, this.entidadesForm.value, type)
            .subscribe(()=> this.location.back()
            ,erro => console.log(erro))
          }else{
            this.customService.save(this.entidadesForm.value, type)
            .subscribe(()=> this.location.back()
            ,erro => console.log(erro))
          }

    }
```

Even you can delete the switch by passing directly the value that contains `secao` and `marca` and use directly the function

```
callRepository(varValue);
```

Comment: for change endpoint based on type in service i need do a if else or switch case, or have a best form?

Comment: use a switch to you have an scalable function may be in the future you want to add another catgory

Comment: event you can delete the switch by passing directly the value that contains `secao` and `marca` and use directly the function  callRepository(varValue);

Comment: thank you very much, i was has more 20 switch case, my code was very big

Comment: Even if it is the case my advice is that recreate your backend service by just passing the type if all services are similar

Answer (score 2):

This is a great use case for polymorphism. Each of your services should implement an `interface`, say `IPersitThings`. Then you can make your switch just assign that variable:

```
let service: IPeristThings;
switch (serviceType) {
   case 'service1':
      service = this.service1;
      break;
   case 'service2':
      service = this.service2;
      break;
}

// Do stuff with service
```

Note that its possible there's a better way than a `switch` to get the appropriate service instance; but not enough details in your question to be sure.

Comment: Watch out, without a `break` this will fall through to `service2`

Comment: @user184994 Good catch; bad switch on my part :)

Comment: thank you for your response, i will edit for give more details for see how i can do it without using switch case